# I'm trying to install Homebrew on my new Nintendo 3DS XL- Problems!

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew on my N3DS and followed all the steps on the online 3ds hacks guide. I have had a problem, I'm working with 1.13.0-45 you see. So that requires going to zoogies GitHub /web/nbhax to launch it. However, when I click the "launch hacks" button, instead of launching Homebrew, Instead mine just reports an error over a black screen on the touch screen.

- YES I have followed the instructions as shown on the website on "how to stop this happening" , so I cleared by internet save data. No change of course or else I wouldn't be here.

Help would be greatly appreciated! If you wish to see a copy of my SD card, please respond and I'll reply with a link.

Comment: There are different methods now. Please check 3ds.hacks.guide for the tutorials.

Comment: What do you mean? That's what I'm using. However I didn't think it wouldn't be different if they had updated the website